# How to achieve pg_dump from a c# application

Tags: c#, postgresql, psql, npgsql

I have a c# application that I want to expose an endpoint to retrieve the provided Postgres Database's schema (just like what pg_dump) gives.

I am looking for suggestions on the best way to achieve this. My application will be running on a container hosted on Kubernetes. Any pointers as to where to start?

Comment: [pg_dump is 20k+ loc of C](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c) dealing with internals of postgres. For your sake, I hope you expect to run the pg_dump executable and process its output, and not try to replicate its functionality.

Comment: Do you have problems starting a process from C#? I think this question needs clarification.